# Система оцениваний в опроснике

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qradiobutton

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть текстовый файл, содержащий 10 вопросов, по три варианта ответа к каждому вопросу. 
На первой строчке находятся ответы в таком формате:

```
1 1 1 2 3 1 1 1 1 3
```

где (1-А, 2-Б, 3-В).

В приложении есть окно, в которое выводится содержимое текстового файла (кроме первой строки с ответами), также в этом окне находятся 10 групп, состоящих из 3 кнопок (`RadioButton`), то есть 30 кнопок, по три на каждый вопрос.

Как сделать сравнение ответов с первой строки текстового файла с нажатыми пользователем кнопками и вывести ответ по типу:

```
Правильно-7 из 10.
```

---

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QLabel

from newrules import Ui_Form as Ui_NewRules  # + Ui_NewRules
from form import Ui_Form as Ui_OpenTest  # + Ui_OpenTest
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(715, 639)
        Form.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(16, 209, 235)")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 571, 621))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                 "color: rgb(216, 209, 235);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 540, 111, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                      "color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 90, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")

        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.radioButton_4 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_4.setObjectName("radioButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButton_4)
        self.radioButton_5 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_5.setObjectName("radioButton_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButton_5)
        self.radioButton_6 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_6.setObjectName("radioButton_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButton_6)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.layoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 140, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_2.setObjectName("layoutWidget_2")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_2)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.radioButton_7 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_2)
        self.radioButton_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_7.setObjectName("radioButton_7")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton_7)
        self.radioButton_8 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_2)
        self.radioButton_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_8.setObjectName("radioButton_8")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton_8)
        self.radioButton_9 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_2)
        self.radioButton_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_9.setObjectName("radioButton_9")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton_9)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.layoutWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 190, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_3.setObjectName("layoutWidget_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.radioButton_10 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.radioButton_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_10.setObjectName("radioButton_10")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.radioButton_10)
        self.radioButton_11 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.radioButton_11.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_11.setObjectName("radioButton_11")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.radioButton_11)
        self.radioButton_12 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.radioButton_12.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_12.setObjectName("radioButton_12")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.radioButton_12)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.layoutWidget_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 240, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_4.setObjectName("layoutWidget_4")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_6)
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.radioButton_13 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.radioButton_13.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_13.setObjectName("radioButton_13")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.radioButton_13)
        self.radioButton_14 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.radioButton_14.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_14.setObjectName("radioButton_14")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.radioButton_14)
        self.radioButton_15 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.radioButton_15.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_15.setObjectName("radioButton_15")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.radioButton_15)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)
        self.layoutWidget_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 290, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_5.setObjectName("layoutWidget_5")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.label_7)
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.radioButton_16 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.radioButton_16.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_16.setObjectName("radioButton_16")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.radioButton_16)
        self.radioButton_17 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.radioButton_17.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_17.setObjectName("radioButton_17")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.radioButton_17)
        self.radioButton_18 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.radioButton_18.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_18.setObjectName("radioButton_18")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.radioButton_18)
        self.verticalLayout_6.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_6)
        self.layoutWidget_6 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 340, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_6.setObjectName("layoutWidget_6")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.label_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_8)
        self.horizontalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_7")
        self.radioButton_19 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.radioButton_19.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_19.setObjectName("radioButton_19")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.radioButton_19)
        self.radioButton_20 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.radioButton_20.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_20.setObjectName("radioButton_20")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.radioButton_20)
        self.radioButton_21 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.radioButton_21.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_21.setObjectName("radioButton_21")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.radioButton_21)
        self.verticalLayout_7.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_7)
        self.layoutWidget_7 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 390, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_7.setObjectName("layoutWidget_7")
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.label_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.label_9)
        self.horizontalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_8.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_8")
        self.radioButton_22 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.radioButton_22.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_22.setObjectName("radioButton_22")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.radioButton_22)
        self.radioButton_23 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.radioButton_23.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_23.setObjectName("radioButton_23")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.radioButton_23)
        self.radioButton_24 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.radioButton_24.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_24.setObjectName("radioButton_24")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.radioButton_24)
        self.verticalLayout_8.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_8)
        self.layoutWidget_8 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 440, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_8.setObjectName("layoutWidget_8")
        self.verticalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setObjectName("verticalLayout_9")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.label_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.label_10)
        self.horizontalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_9.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_9")
        self.radioButton_25 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.radioButton_25.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_25.setObjectName("radioButton_25")
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.radioButton_25)
        self.radioButton_26 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.radioButton_26.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_26.setObjectName("radioButton_26")
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.radioButton_26)
        self.radioButton_27 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.radioButton_27.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_27.setObjectName("radioButton_27")
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.radioButton_27)
        self.verticalLayout_9.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_9)
        self.layoutWidget_9 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 490, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_9.setObjectName("layoutWidget_9")
        self.verticalLayout_10 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.verticalLayout_10.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_10.setObjectName("verticalLayout_10")

        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.label_11.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.verticalLayout_10.addWidget(self.label_11)
        self.horizontalLayout_10 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_10.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_10")
        self.radioButton_28 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.radioButton_28.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_28.setObjectName("radioButton_28")
        self.horizontalLayout_10.addWidget(self.radioButton_28)
        self.radioButton_29 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.radioButton_29.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_29.setObjectName("radioButton_29")
        self.horizontalLayout_10.addWidget(self.radioButton_29)
        self.radioButton_30 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.radioButton_30.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_30.setObjectName("radioButton_30")
        self.horizontalLayout_10.addWidget(self.radioButton_30)
        self.verticalLayout_10.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_10)

        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 40, 111, 41))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")

        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.widget)
        self.radioButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton)

        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.widget)
        self.radioButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_2)

        self.radioButton_3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.widget)
        self.radioButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_3)

        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Завершить тест"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "№2"))
        self.radioButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_5.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_6.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "№3"))
        self.radioButton_7.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_8.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_9.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Form", "№4"))
        self.radioButton_10.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_11.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_12.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Form", "№5"))
        self.radioButton_13.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_14.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_15.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Form", "№6"))
        self.radioButton_16.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_17.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_18.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("Form", "№7"))
        self.radioButton_19.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_20.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_21.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("Form", "№8"))
        self.radioButton_22.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_23.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_24.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("Form", "№9"))
        self.radioButton_25.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_26.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_27.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("Form", "№10"))
        self.radioButton_28.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_29.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_30.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "№1"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(763, 544)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(16, 209, 235);\n"
                                 "")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 48, 711, 441))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.text_zagolovok = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.layoutWidget)
        self.text_zagolovok.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 100))
        self.text_zagolovok.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 100))
        self.text_zagolovok.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                          "color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.text_zagolovok.setObjectName("text_zagolovok")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.text_zagolovok)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")

class LastWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)



class NewRules(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_NewRules):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.write_file)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.start_test)


        self.answers = None  # +++
        self.questions = None  # +++
        self.lastWindow = LastWindow()  # +++
        self.lastWindow.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.finish_test)  # +++
        self.rb_answers = {  # +++
            0: [self.lastWindow.radioButton,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_2,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_3],
            1: [self.lastWindow.radioButton_4,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_5,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_6],
            2: [self.lastWindow.radioButton_7,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_8,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_9],
            3: [self.lastWindow.radioButton_10,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_11,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_12],
            4: [self.lastWindow.radioButton_13,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_14,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_15],
            5: [self.lastWindow.radioButton_16,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_17,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_18],
            6: [self.lastWindow.radioButton_19,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_20,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_21],
            7: [self.lastWindow.radioButton_22,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_23,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_24],
            8: [self.lastWindow.radioButton_25,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_26,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_27],
            9: [self.lastWindow.radioButton_28,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_29,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_30],
        }


    def write_file(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self,
            'Open File',
            '',
            '*.txt'
        )
        if not fileName:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', 'Добавте файл с тестом')
            return

        with open(fileName, "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
            self.answers = f.readline()
            self.questions = f.readlines()

    def start_test(self):
        if self.answers is None:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                None, 'Внимание', 'Добавте файл с тестом')
            return

        self.newRules = NewRules()

        self.newRules.push_btn_starttest.clicked.connect(self.window4)  # !!! +++

        self.newRules.show()
        self.hide()

   
    def window4(self):
        if self.questions is None:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', 'Добавте файл с тестом')
            return
        self.lastWindow.show()
        self.newRules.hide()

        self.lastWindow.label.clear()
        self.lastWindow.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont('TimesNewRoman', 15))
        for line in self.questions:
            self.lastWindow.label.setText(self.lastWindow.label.text() + line)

    def finish_test(self):
        answers = self.answers.split()
        # print(f'def finish_test(self): {answers}')

        self.lastWindow.label.clear()
        for i, q in enumerate(self.questions):
            # print(f'question: {i+1} -- {q}')
            answer = answers[i]

            rbs = self.rb_answers[i]
            rb_answer = '\tВы не отвечали на этот вопрос.\n'
            for j, rb in enumerate(rbs):
                if rb.isChecked():
                    if answer == str(j + 1):
                        rb_answer = '\tОтвет правильный.\n'
                    else:
                        rb_answer = '\tОтвет НЕ правильный.\n'
                    break
            self.lastWindow.label.setText(
                self.lastWindow.label.text() + q + rb_answer)
 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Создать массив правильных ответов и сравнивать ответ из каждого окна с элементом этого массива. Индекс окна с вопросом - это индекс в массиве правильных ответов. Чего сложного?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я полностью переделал форму `class Ui_Form(object).`

- виджеты вставлены в менеджер компоновки (попробуйте изменять размеры этого окна);
- `QRadioButton` добавлены в `QButtonGroup`.

Очень внимательно смотрите как вам заполнять **файл.txt**
Вам надо сделать вставку:

```
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

**111.txt**

```
2 1 1 2 3 1 1 1 1 3
Как называется группа файлов, которая хранится отдельной группой и имеет собственное имя? <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;А Байт Б Каталог В Дискета
<br>Вопрос  2 ... <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;А Байт Б Каталог В Дискета
<br>Вопрос  3 ... <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;А Байт Б Каталог В Дискета
<br>Вопрос  4 ... <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;А Байт Б Каталог В Дискета
<br>Вопрос  5 ... <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;А Байт Б Каталог В Дискета
<br>Вопрос  6 ... <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;А Байт Б Каталог В Дискета
<br>Вопрос  7 ... <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;А Байт Б Каталог В Дискета
<br>Вопрос  8 ... <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;А Байт Б Каталог В Дискета
<br>Вопрос  9 ... <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;А Байт Б Каталог В Дискета
<br>Вопрос 10 ... <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;А Байт Б Каталог В Дискета
```

---

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QLabel
from q1496576_newrules import Ui_Form as Ui_NewRules  


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(800, 640)
        Form.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(16, 209, 235)")
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 571, 621))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                 "color: rgb(16, 09, 35);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 540, 111, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                      "color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 90, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")

        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton)

        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_2)

        self.radioButton_3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)        
# +++ vvvvv       
        self.bg1 = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self.layoutWidget)
        self.bg1.addButton(self.radioButton)
        self.bg1.addButton(self.radioButton_2)
        self.bg1.addButton(self.radioButton_3)
# +++ ^^^^^       

        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_3)
        
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.radioButton_4 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_4.setObjectName("radioButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButton_4)
        self.radioButton_5 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_5.setObjectName("radioButton_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButton_5)
        self.radioButton_6 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_6.setObjectName("radioButton_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButton_6)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
# +++ vvvvv       
        self.bg2 = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self.layoutWidget)
        self.bg2.addButton(self.radioButton_4)
        self.bg2.addButton(self.radioButton_5)
        self.bg2.addButton(self.radioButton_6)
# +++ ^^^^^ и так далее

        
#        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_2)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)              # +++   
        
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
#        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_4)                   # +++
        
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.radioButton_7 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_7.setObjectName("radioButton_7")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton_7)
        self.radioButton_8 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_8.setObjectName("radioButton_8")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton_8)
        self.radioButton_9 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_9.setObjectName("radioButton_9")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton_9)
        
#        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)           # +++
        self.bg3 = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self.layoutWidget)
        self.bg3.addButton(self.radioButton_7)
        self.bg3.addButton(self.radioButton_8)
        self.bg3.addButton(self.radioButton_9)        

        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.radioButton_10 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_10.setObjectName("radioButton_10")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.radioButton_10)
        self.radioButton_11 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_11.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_11.setObjectName("radioButton_11")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.radioButton_11)
        self.radioButton_12 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_12.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_12.setObjectName("radioButton_12")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.radioButton_12)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.bg4 = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self.layoutWidget)
        self.bg4.addButton(self.radioButton_10)
        self.bg4.addButton(self.radioButton_11)
        self.bg4.addButton(self.radioButton_12) 

        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_6)
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.radioButton_13 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_13.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_13.setObjectName("radioButton_13")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.radioButton_13)
        self.radioButton_14 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_14.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_14.setObjectName("radioButton_14")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.radioButton_14)
        self.radioButton_15 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_15.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_15.setObjectName("radioButton_15")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.radioButton_15)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)
        self.bg5 = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self.layoutWidget)
        self.bg5.addButton(self.radioButton_13)
        self.bg5.addButton(self.radioButton_14)
        self.bg5.addButton(self.radioButton_15) 

        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_7)
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.radioButton_16 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_16.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_16.setObjectName("radioButton_16")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.radioButton_16)
        self.radioButton_17 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_17.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_17.setObjectName("radioButton_17")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.radioButton_17)
        self.radioButton_18 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_18.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_18.setObjectName("radioButton_18")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.radioButton_18)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_6)
        self.bg6 = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self.layoutWidget)
        self.bg6.addButton(self.radioButton_16)
        self.bg6.addButton(self.radioButton_17)
        self.bg6.addButton(self.radioButton_18) 

        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_8)
        self.horizontalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_7")
        self.radioButton_19 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_19.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_19.setObjectName("radioButton_19")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.radioButton_19)
        self.radioButton_20 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_20.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_20.setObjectName("radioButton_20")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.radioButton_20)
        self.radioButton_21 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_21.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_21.setObjectName("radioButton_21")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.radioButton_21)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_7)
        self.bg7 = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self.layoutWidget)
        self.bg7.addButton(self.radioButton_19)
        self.bg7.addButton(self.radioButton_20)
        self.bg7.addButton(self.radioButton_21) 

        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_9)
        self.horizontalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_8.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_8")
        self.radioButton_22 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_22.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_22.setObjectName("radioButton_22")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.radioButton_22)
        self.radioButton_23 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_23.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_23.setObjectName("radioButton_23")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.radioButton_23)
        self.radioButton_24 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_24.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_24.setObjectName("radioButton_24")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.radioButton_24)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_8)
        self.bg8 = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self.layoutWidget)
        self.bg8.addButton(self.radioButton_22)
        self.bg8.addButton(self.radioButton_23)
        self.bg8.addButton(self.radioButton_24) 

        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_10)
        self.horizontalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_9.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_9")
        self.radioButton_25 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_25.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_25.setObjectName("radioButton_25")
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.radioButton_25)
        self.radioButton_26 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_26.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_26.setObjectName("radioButton_26")
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.radioButton_26)
        self.radioButton_27 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_27.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_27.setObjectName("radioButton_27")
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.radioButton_27)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_9)
        self.bg9 = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self.layoutWidget)
        self.bg9.addButton(self.radioButton_25)
        self.bg9.addButton(self.radioButton_26)
        self.bg9.addButton(self.radioButton_27) 

        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_11.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_11)
        self.horizontalLayout_10 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_10.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_10")
        self.radioButton_28 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_28.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_28.setObjectName("radioButton_28")
        self.horizontalLayout_10.addWidget(self.radioButton_28)
        self.radioButton_29 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_29.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_29.setObjectName("radioButton_29")
        self.horizontalLayout_10.addWidget(self.radioButton_29)
        self.radioButton_30 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_30.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_30.setObjectName("radioButton_30")
        self.horizontalLayout_10.addWidget(self.radioButton_30)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_10)
        self.bg10 = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self.layoutWidget)
        self.bg10.addButton(self.radioButton_28)
        self.bg10.addButton(self.radioButton_29)
        self.bg10.addButton(self.radioButton_30) 
        
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Завершить тест"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "№2"))
        self.radioButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_5.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_6.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "№3"))
        self.radioButton_7.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_8.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_9.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Form", "№4"))
        self.radioButton_10.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_11.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_12.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Form", "№5"))
        self.radioButton_13.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_14.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_15.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Form", "№6"))
        self.radioButton_16.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_17.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_18.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("Form", "№7"))
        self.radioButton_19.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_20.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_21.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("Form", "№8"))
        self.radioButton_22.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_23.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_24.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("Form", "№9"))
        self.radioButton_25.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_26.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_27.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("Form", "№10"))
        self.radioButton_28.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_29.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_30.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "№1"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    ...

class LastWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
# +++ vvvvvvv        
        self.pushButton.setMinimumHeight(41)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)                                # !!! +++

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)                   # !!! +++
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 4, 5)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.layoutWidget, 0, 5, 3, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 3, 5, 1, 1)
# +++ ^^^^^^^

class NewRules(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_NewRules):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    ...

    def window4(self):
        if self.questions is None:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', 'Добавте файл с тестом')
            return
        self.lastWindow.show()
        self.newRules.hide()

        self.lastWindow.label.clear()
        self.lastWindow.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont('TimesNewRoman', 10))    # + 10 ?
        for line in self.questions:
            self.lastWindow.label.setText(self.lastWindow.label.text() + line)

    def finish_test(self):
        answers = self.answers.split()
        self.lastWindow.label.clear()
        
        correct_answers = 0                                             # +++
        all_answers = 0                                                 # +++
        
        for i, q in enumerate(self.questions):
            # print(f'question: {i+1} -- {q}')
            answer = answers[i]

            rbs = self.rb_answers[i]
# +++                    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
            rb_answer = '<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Вы не отвечали на этот вопрос.\n'
            for j, rb in enumerate(rbs):
                if rb.isChecked():
                    if answer == str(j + 1):
# +++                                vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
                        rb_answer = '<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ответ правильный.\n'
                        correct_answers += 1                         # +++
                    else:
# +++                                vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
                        rb_answer = '<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ответ НЕ правильный.\n'
                    break
                
            self.lastWindow.label.setText(
                self.lastWindow.label.text() + q + rb_answer)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
            all_answers += 1                                         # +++

        if correct_answers / all_answers * 100 >= 70:
            text = 'Отличный результат.' 
        elif correct_answers / all_answers * 100 >= 50:
            text = 'Удовлетворительный результат.'
        else:
            text = 'Попробуйте тест пройти еще раз.'
            
        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
            self, 
            'Рузультат', 
            f'Правильно - {correct_answers} из {all_answers}. \n{text}.')  

#        self.lastWindow.pushButton.setEnabled(False)                # +++
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: S.Nick, можете добавить код из окна LastWindow

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QLabel

from q1496576_newrules import Ui_Form as Ui_NewRules  #
#from form import Ui_Form as Ui_OpenTest  #


class Ui_Form(object):
    ...

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    ...

class LastWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    ...

class NewRules(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_NewRules):
    ...

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
   
    ...


    def finish_test(self):
        answers = self.answers.split()
        # print(f'def finish_test(self): {answers}')

        self.lastWindow.label.clear()
        
        correct_answers = 0                                          # +++
        all_answers = 0                                              # +++
        
        for i, q in enumerate(self.questions):
            # print(f'question: {i+1} -- {q}')
            answer = answers[i]

            rbs = self.rb_answers[i]
            rb_answer = '\tВы не отвечали на этот вопрос.\n'
            for j, rb in enumerate(rbs):
                if rb.isChecked():
                    if answer == str(j + 1):
                        rb_answer = '\tОтвет правильный.\n'
                        correct_answers += 1                         # +++
                    else:
                        rb_answer = '\tОтвет НЕ правильный.\n'
                    break
                
            self.lastWindow.label.setText(
                self.lastWindow.label.text() + q + rb_answer)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
            all_answers += 1                                         # +++

        if correct_answers / all_answers * 100 >= 70:
            text = 'Отличный результат.' 
        elif correct_answers / all_answers * 100 >= 50:
            text = 'Удовлетворительный результат.'
        else:
            text = 'Попробуйте тест пройти еще раз.'
            
        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
            self, 
            'Рузультат', 
            f'Правильно - {correct_answers} из {all_answers}. \n{text}.')  

#        self.lastWindow.pushButton.setEnabled(False)                # +++
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: с моим файлом это не работает. В моем пробном файле после вопроса сразу на следующих 3 строчках три варианта ответа. С таким файлом не работает, но если вопрос и варианты ответов будут на одной строчке, то все будет работать корректно, но текста файла не будет видно в окне

Comment: @flikky я вас совсем не понимаю. Вы написали: "На первой строчке находятся ответы". Сейчас вы пишите: "...  после вопроса сразу на следующих 3 строчках три варианта ответа". О каких трех вариантых ответа вы говорите, т.е. у вас один ответ - хороший, второй - так себе, а третий - плохой или как? Заметьте вы даже не НЕ ПРИКРЕПИЛИ свой текстовый файл. В общем не работает, так не работает.

Comment: 1 строчка- ответы, после нее идут вопросы, то есть вопрос, после него 3 варианта ответа, и так 10 вопросов

Comment: Пример-Вопрос 1 - Как называется группа файлов, которая хранится отдельной группой и имеет собственное имя ?
А Байт
Б Каталог
В Дискета